# What is the minimum level of isolation needed?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, isolation-level, acid

I want to use versions for a transaction for java application. That is, I will have `select name, version from table_name where ...`, and `update table_name set name ='new name', version =:version+1 where vesion = :version` executed in one transaction. Using such a transaction, I'm trying to get records that I haven't processed yet. What is the minimum transaction isolation level from which I will correctly receive data?

Comment: In which DBMS? How many parallel sessions can do the same?

Comment: @astentx I use Oracle. Maybe about 20 sessions

Answer (score 1):

**`Read Uncommitted`** - will see the same as Read Committed + dirty uncommitted changes, you do not need it at all.

**`Read Committed`** - will NOT see dirty changes, but will see pfantoms, non-repeatable reads, lost updates are possible because another transaction can commit changes and affect your updates. These phenomenas are usually okay for described scenario.  Read Committed does not require read-locks to be kept till the end of transactioand this is **lowest level for the use-case and recommended**.

Higher level is **`Repeatable Read`** - to guarantee repeatable reads and absence of lost updates, database keeps read and write locks until the end of the transaction.
This level allows only phantom reads which are possible because range locks are not acquired. Usually you do not need that strict level, because normally non-repeatable reads are okay - you can receive different data after repeating select, lost updates are also okay for your use-case.

The highest level is **`Serializable`** - should be the same as serial execution of transactions when next transaction begins only when previous ends. You will not see others committed updates, no phantom reads, no non-repeateble reads, no lost updates because only one transaction can operate the range of data. You do not need that locking definitely

So, Read Committed is the answer. If you want to double-check, think which bugs can cause each phenomena possible. For example if you read uncommitted dirty record, modify and commit it - it looks like huge bug.